# why caffe use #define macros to create function

Tags: c++, macros, caffe

I am reading Caffe's source code, I'm curious why caffe use #define to create functions like in the caffe.cpp.

```
#define RegisterBrewFunction(func) \
namespace { \
class __Registerer_##func { \
 public: /* NOLINT */ \
  __Registerer_##func() { \
    g_brew_map[#func] = &func; \
  } \
}; \
__Registerer_##func g_registerer_##func; \
}
```

They use RegisterBrewFunction to register functions, there must be some advantages. They can just use if else to decide which function to call, can anyone tell me why write codes in this way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The macro doesn't just create a function; it creates a class definition, a constructor for that class, and an object of that type, all in the anonymous namespace. The effect of all that code is to add the address of the user-defined function `func` to a database of functions. While that's a lot of code, it's intended to make it easier for users to register functions.

Comment: So when we receive args, why don't just use if and else clause to decide which function to call, why we should register these functions in advance.

Comment: @zhichai -- because if/else pretty much requires that you know in advance which functions you might want to call. The point of registration is that as you build your code base and you add functions you don't have to go back to the if/else chain and rewrite it.

Comment: Thanks, I think i got you.